Can't compile anchor typescript project
I have a typescript project in which I am only doing
import * as anchor from '@coral-xyz/anchor';

Yet if I try to compile this with tsc, I get the following weird error:
node_modules/@coral-xyz/anchor/dist/cjs/program/namespace/simulate.d.ts:45:170 - error TS2344: Type 'AllEvents<IDL>[number]' does not satisfy the constraint 'IdlEvent'.
  Type '([IdlTypeDef] extends [{ name: NonNullable<IDL["events"]>[number]["name"]; }] ? [{ name: NonNullable<IDL["events"]>[number]["name"]; } & IdlTypeDef] : [])[number]' is not assignable to type 'IdlEvent'.
    Property 'discriminator' is missing in type '{ name: NonNullable<IDL["events"]>[number]["name"]; } & IdlTypeDef' but required in type 'IdlEvent'.

45 export type SimulateNamespace<IDL extends Idl = Idl, I extends AllInstructions<IDL> = AllInstructions<IDL>> = MakeInstructionsNamespace<IDL, I, Promise<SimulateResponse<AllEvents<IDL>[number], IdlTypes<IDL>>>>;
                                                                                                                                                                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  node_modules/@coral-xyz/anchor/dist/cjs/idl.d.ts:82:5
    82     discriminator: IdlDiscriminator;
           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    'discriminator' is declared here.
...

Found 2 errors in the same file, starting at: node_modules/@coral-xyz/anchor/dist/cjs/program/namespace/simulate.d.ts

Since I'm guessing this is related to my typescript setup, here's my tsconfig and my package.json:
tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "ESNext",
    "target": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*"
  ]
}

package.json
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "build/index.mjs",
  "scripts": {
    "compile": "tsc"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "description": "",
  "type": "module",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/bn.js": "^5.1.6",
    "typescript": "^5.6.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@coral-xyz/anchor": "^0.30.1"
  }
}


Found my answer: Turns out at the time of this writing (anchor v0.30.1 is the latest version) doesn't support typescript v5.x . Fortunately a PR fixing this has been merged already here so this should be resolved when the next anchor version is released.
